# Deleting data from a SQL table after it is altered in another

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have three tables for managing stock levels - `Product`, `ProductGender` and `ProductType`. I also have a table called `OrderItem` that defines what is being ordered from the database.

After I have my program insert values into the `OrderItem` table, it identifies how much is to be ordered after the user inserts the amount into a field.

My question is - how do I subtract the amount of stock ordered from the amount of stock in the table `ProductType`? I know I will need some form of `DELETE` statement but I'm not sure quite how to craft a sufficient statement.

Comment: what is the connection between product type table and order item table?

Comment: Product ID is used in both tables. ProductID defines the name, amount, size etc.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need an `UPDATE` rather than an `DELETE`. That being said, I would *not* advise to update the stock *after* having accepted the order. I feel it more manageable the other way around: update the stock, and accept the order *only* if there was enough items.

Something like that:

```
--> client place an order for 20 item id XXXX:

UPDATE ProductType SET amount = amount - 20
 WHERE amount >= 20 AND item_id = 'XXXX';
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Please note that "guard" clause
```

That statement will either update 0 or 1 row. 1 row means "ok, stock updated". 0 means "not enough items left in stock". This is especially important in multi-user environment where you can have several concurrent updates of your stock for the same item.

After that only:

```
--> If 1 row updated

INSERT INTO OrderItem(..., amount) VALUES (....., 20);
```

Finally, in a real world application, you need to wrap all those statements in a transaction in case of unexpected failure after the stock update.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know correctly what you are expecting.Assuming

If table `ProductType --> type1    amount`

Then inserting to table `OrderItem` n items of `type1`.So assuming that you have to `decrease` that much amount from `ProductType`

When you insert `n` amount into `OrderItem`,

Here you can use `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE OrderItem SET column_name = column_name - n WHERE ...
```

**Update**

update the stock, and accept the order only if there was enough items, is the good process steps.

Hope this helps

Comment: How do I refer to the `ProductType` table in the `UPDATE` statement? Would it be something along the lines of `"UPDATE OrderItem SET amountordered = ProductType.amountinstock - n WHERE amountordered=?"`

Comment: why dont you try to put a variable `amount` to decrease or inrease?